# Late Answers: How Late is Late?

Tags: support, review

In the [help center](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/help/review-late-answers), it says:

> The Late answers queue contains answers that were posted by new users much later than when the question was asked.

What timespan is "much later"?

Comment: It seems like it might be more appropriate to post this in Meta SE.

Comment: I found [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177552/how-old-does-a-question-have-to-be-for-it-to-be-a-late-answer) on Meta SE.  Thirty days seems a fairly low threshold, but there is also a filter on reputation of the user posting the Late Answer.